# Filter publish content in Meteor

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe

I would like to create a list of students that aren't attending a teachers class.

This list is designed to show a teacher all the students who haven't registered for their class.

- Teacher accounts contain classes they teach.
- Student accounts contain classes they will be attending.

I'm not sure if it's possible to check the teachers (the current user) account for classes they teach and then filter out all student that have already selected that class when you publish the data. I've tried a number of variations but nothing is working.

Path: `schemas.js`

```
Schema.classes = new SimpleSchema({
        class: {
        type: [String],
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "select-checkbox",
            options: function () {
                return [
                {label: "Maths", value: 'Maths' },
                {label: "English", value: 'English'},
                {label: "Science", value: 'Science'},
                ];
            },
            afFormGroup: {
              label: false
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Path: `publish.js`

```
Meteor.publish('classes', function () {
     return Meteor.users.find({roles:'is_student'});
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor - Creating a variable within publish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784424/meteor-creating-a-variable-within-publish)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your documents are structured as follows:

```
Users.insert({
  firstName: "Matthias",
  lastName: "Eckhart",
  isTeacher: true,
  classes: ["Secure Coding", "Hacking", "Software Design", "Software Quality", "Entrepreneurship"],
  office: "C221"
});
Users.insert({
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  isTeacher: false,
  classes: ["Hacking", "Entrepreneurship", "Secure Coding"],
});
Users.insert({
  firstName: "Jane",
  lastName: "Doe",
  isTeacher: false,
  classes: ["Web Design", "Database Design", "Hacking"],
});
Users.insert({
  firstName: "Richard",
  lastName: "Roe",
  isTeacher: false,
  classes: ["English", "German"],
});
```

---

Then, you could get all students who do not have a certain class present in their `classes` array by using the **[`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)** MongoDB comparison query operator:

```
Users.find({
  isTeacher: false,
  classes: {
    $nin: ["Hacking"] // Add the classes you want to filter out here
  }
});
```

If you want to get students who do not attend **all** classes taught by a certain teacher, you could combine the **[`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/)** and the **[`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)** operator:

```
Users.find({
  isTeacher: false,
  classes: {
    $not: {
      $all: ["Secure Coding", "Hacking", "Software Design", "Software Quality", "Entrepreneurship"]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for trying Matthias. I don't think I explained what I was asking for well enough. I reposted with reduced code snip it this morning. Feel free to check it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784424/meteor-creating-a-variable-within-publish?noredirect=1#comment59240768_35784424