# Meteor - Creating a variable within publish

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm try to get the below publish function to work. I would like to retrieve all users who do not have a class that the current user has in their `profile.classes` array. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Meteor.publish('classes', function () {

  var class = Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},{fields: {"profile.classes": 1}});

  var users = Meteor.users.find({
    roles:'is_student',
    "profile.classes": { $ne : class } 
    }});

   return users;
});
```

Comment: `var class = Meteor.users.find( /* ... */ ).fetch()[0].classes`? Or use `findOne` to avoid the `fetch`. `find` returns a Mongo cursor, not a document or a field of that document.

Comment: Is `classes` supposed to be an array or single field?

Comment: I think an array, since there could be maths, science, english etc

Comment: `var class = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId},{fields: {"profile.classes": 1}}).classes;`

Comment: So are you asking for all users who have a class in the current user's classes?  Also, what is `group` for in your code?

Comment: Ok, so now something strange is happening. Thanks @Kyll The code above appears to work which is great but now my `"profile.classes": { $ne : class }` appears to be publishing all the results where it  is equal to class. I thought `$ne` should return anything that doesn't equal `class`.

Comment: Hi Stephen, sorry I'm asking for all users who **don't** have class in the current users classes. The **group** is to do with roles. I forgot to remove it for the code snippet. I'll update now.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to provide a sample data structure (what is `classes`? An array of strings? A string?), and the updated version of your code and issue? That way we have a full [mcve] to work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `profile.classes` holds an array of strings and that you want to get all users who DO NOT have a class in the current user's classes, here is some code to do what you're asking for:

```
Meteor.publish('classes', function ( ) {

  var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId},{fields: {"profile.classes": 1}});
  if( user && user.profile && user.profile.classes ) {
    return Meteor.users.find({ roles: 'is_student', 'profile.classes': { $nin: user.profile.classes } });
  } else {
    return this.ready();
  }
});
```

The important line of that code is:

```
return Meteor.users.find({ roles: 'is_student', 
            'profile.classes': { $nin: user.profile.classes } });
```

The key part here is the `$nin`. From [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/):

> `$nin` selects the documents where:
>    - the field value is not in the specified array or
>    - the field does not exist.

So this should select users who either don't have a `profile.classes` array field, or have none of the classes the current user has.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! This worked a treat. I just had to tinker a little to get it to work with my other conditions, hence the delay. Thanks again.